# No Custom Field named found Custom report type

Tags: ant, custom-report-type, jenkins

I have a custom report type of category Accounts & Contacts, on running the Jenkins build, I am receiving the following error. The field mentioned here

```
reportTypes/GEFUE_Accounts_Related_Contacts.reportType -- Error: In field: field - no CustomField named AccountContactRelation.Sales_Organisation__c found (line 1801, column 18)
```

And on line 1801 I have following xml in the report type

```
<columns>
    <checkedByDefault>false</checkedByDefault>
    <field>Sales_Organisation__c</field>
    <table>Account.AccountContactRelations</table>
</columns>
```

I checked the field mentioned here `AccountContactRelation.Sales_Organisation__c` in error is already present in the layout. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Was the field created after the report type already existed? New custom fields won’t be added automatically to custom report types. Try editting the report type’s layout and confirm if the field is there.

Comment: Yes the field already existed, and it is there in the layout.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Sir, did you get any resolution for this? I am facing the same issue.